# PowerShell Run Macro with dynamic parameter

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute some macros though my powershell in a dynamic way. I receive a dictionary with macro names and parameters and need to execute it.

This is the code.

Imagine that in `$ParamContent` I have the following variables: `"Param 1"+'#'+"Param 2"+'#'+"Param 3"`

```bsh
$arguments = $MacroName + "'"

$ParamContent = $MacroParams.Split("{#}")

for ($i=0; $i -lt $ParamContent.count;$i++) {
    #$arguments += ",'" + $ParamContent[$i] + "'"
    $arguments += ",'" + $ParamContent[$i] + "'"
}

$arguments = $arguments.Substring(0,$arguments.Length-1)
write-host $arguments

$xl.run.Invoke($arguments)
```

The actual error is the following:

> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception
>   calling "Run" with "31" argument(s): "Cannot run the macro
>   'Connections.openConnThroughParameters','RMDeriv','RMDeriv_uat','UAT'.
>   The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be
>   disabled." ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot
>   run the macro
>   'Connections.openConnThroughParameters','RMDeriv','RMDeriv_uat','UAT'.
>   The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be
>   disabled. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot run the
>   macro 'Connections.openConnThroughParameters','Param 1','Param
>   2','Param 3'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all
>   macros may be disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using to quote the arguments is not correct as it leaves out the first quote character on the macro name itself. Furthermore, numeric parameters need not be quoted unless your macro can convert these values given as string back to numeric types.

Perhaps using a small helper function to do the quoting might help:

```
function Quote-Param([object[]]$param) {
    # helper function to return given parameter(s) quoted unless they are numeric
    [decimal]$number = 0
    foreach ($p in $param) {
        if ([decimal]::TryParse($p, [ref]$number)) { $p } else { ('"{0}"' -f $p) }
    }
}

$MacroParams = "Param 1#Param 2#Param 3#123#blah#456.789"
$MacroName   = 'MyMacro'

$arguments = @(Quote-Param $MacroName)  # force as array for the first argument
$arguments +=  Quote-Param $MacroParams.Split("#")
$arguments = $arguments -join ','

Write-Host $arguments -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

This will return a `$arguments` string:

```
"MyMacro","Param 1","Param 2","Param 3",123,"blah",123456.789
```

---

**Edit**

Your code does not show how you create the `$xl` object, probably using `$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application`.

After creating the object, you can set some properties like `$xl.Visible = $false`. There is also a property you can set that allows running macros or not called `AutomationSecurity`.

To enable macros:

```
$xl.AutomationSecurity = 1  # msoAutomationSecurityLow
```

You can set this property to any of these values:

```
 Constant                          Value  Description
 --------                          -----  -----------
 msoAutomationSecurityLow          1      Enables all macros
 msoAutomationSecurityByUI         2      Uses the security setting specified in the Security dialog box
 msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable 3      Disables all macros in all files opened programmatically without showing any security alerts
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @Theo for you reply, however it seems a problem when invoking the method.

In this part of code `$xl.run.Invoke($arguments)` it is giving me the following error:

_System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Run" with "31" argument(s): "Cannot run the macro "Connections.openConnThroughParameters","Param1","Param2","Param3"'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."_

The code is more clean now with your function but I think I'm using the wrong way to call a Macro passing parameters dinamically.

Comment: @FelipeCabralJerônimo The error message also suggests that you have opened the workbook with macros disabled. Please see my edited answer.